# Проблема с HDD диском (разделами)

Tags: hdd, disk

У меня проблема с HDD (1тб) диском в ноуте. Проблема заключается в том что я установил туда UBUNTU (20.04) выделил 100гб в разделе управление дисками. И вот на днях его удалил (переустановил загрузчик винды в BIOS) и теперь этот 100гб просто висит нельзя добавить его туда откуда брал, а также создание нового тома. Думаю что там остался сам UBUNTU не удаленным поэтому такие проблемы. Пробовал отформатировать сам HDD (в разделе управление дисками), но форматируется оставшийся 900гб, а тот 100гб с ним нельзя ничего делать, пробовал установить обратно туда же UBUNTU, выдает ошибку, пытался форматировать через POWERSELL (aдминистратор) показывал какую-то ошибку (форматировался оставшийся 900гб) не тот 100. Помогите пожалуйста как можно фиксить это?

Хотелось бы (как-то найти) в настройках HDD сбросить до заводских настроек. Чтобы было как впервые.

Comment: Снести всю информацию о разделах (затереть сигнатуру 55АА в МБР) и разметить "с нуля".

Comment: `wipefs --all --force /dev/DISK`, где нужный `DISK` можно узнать через `lsblk`

Comment: `и теперь этот 100гб просто висит нельзя добавить его туда откуда брал` похоже вы просто удалили его содержимое(вайпнули) но не сам раздел. поковыряйтесь внимательнее в утилите - размечалке дисков. а именно, если утилита графическая, кликните по этим 100гб лкм, там ищите "удалить" и подобные пункты(на вскидку, есть как минимум 3 варианта удаления: удалить содержимое, удалить название[или букву или метку], удалить раздел) + `merge` по сути должно дать схожий эффект если оставшаяся часть тоже является разделом

Comment: Добавьте каких-нибудь скриншотов или текстового вывода каких-нибудь утилит с информацией об этом разделе, так будет гораздо проще ответить на ваш вопрос.